# Redirecting http requests to git resources to github.com

Tags: github

I'm wondering if it would be possible to use vanity URLs for git repositories without to mirror the repository itself. Basically to just and issue redirects. Example: I would like to make my github repository available on mydomain.com/repoName. When someone tries to clone push etc to this remote I would issue a redirect to github.com/myusername/myrepo. Is a such thing possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a *git* issue. It's about redirecting http requests to corresponding URLs on github. I don't know if there's anything that does it "out of the box" but given the nice resources names on github, I think a few  lines in your http server config file should do it.

Comment: The http redirect would be trivial but I was a bit concerned that some may clone the repository through SSH or authenticate against the repo using SSH. How would that work?

Comment: If your domain is not running an ssh server, they wouldn't be able to connect to that anyway. I'm not sure I see the problem.